# Replace strings with incrementing value

Tags: java, parsing

I have an ArrayList that is built from posts in a forum, each entry is a post.
When I am building the entry I am replacing all  elements with the string "Image[x]".
After the array list is filled I want to go back and replace all instances of "[x]" with an incrementing integer.

I am building my array list using this code:

```
Elements wholePosts = doc.select("div.post_body");
            for (Element wholePost : wholePosts) {
            Elements texts = wholePost.select("div[itemprop=commentText]");
            for (Element text : texts) {

                String nobr = text.html().replaceAll("(?i)<br[^>]*>", "newlineplaceholder");
                String formatted1 = nobr.replaceAll("<img src=.*?>", "Image[x]");
                Document finalPost = Jsoup.parse(formatted1);
                String almostfinalText = finalPost.text();
                String finalText = almostfinalText.replace("newlineplaceholder", "\n");


                datumList.add(finalText);

            }
```

I have tried to replace the string and increment it in the above code but it only increments for each post element, so if there are multiple images in a post, post 1 would contain "Image1, Image1" and post 2 would contain "Image2, Image2". What I am looking for is for post 1 to contain "Image1, Image2" and post 2 to contain "Image3, Image4"

Comment: Where is the code that replaces the "[x]"s?

Comment: You need to replace one "[x]" at a time, rather than replacing them all at once in a given string.

Comment: Create an `int imageCounter` variable initialized as 1, embed its string representation into your *Image* string and increment it afterwards. You can do it right away (as Code-Guru already suggested) and there will be no need to do any replacements later.

Comment: I've tried multiple ways to replace it with an integer value, the issue being that I end up with the integer staying the same for every instance of an image in a given array list index. Here is the latest bit I tried;  `for (int i= 0; i < datumList.size(); i++) {
   if(datumList.get(i).contains("Image[x]")) {
    String value = datumList.get(i);
    value = value.replace("[x]",""+count);
    datumList.set(i,value);
    count++;
   } }`